# How to show EasyTipView above my Button in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tooltip

So I have a few buttons in my app that i want to show tool tips above. I am using the module EasyTipView but it shows the tool tip below my button, I want the tool tip above my buttons. Can anyone please help, I am super new to iOS and I know it's an easy task but I am unable to find a solution.
https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView

Comment: What's an EasyTipView? I gather it's a third party framework? You should add a link to it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found EasyTipView. It looks like it is on github at https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView. Is that it?

If so, that class has a property arrowPosition. The "Usage" section of the readme says:

> Usage
>
> First you should customize the preferences:

```
var preferences = EasyTipView.Preferences()
// deleted other preferences settings that aren't relevant 
preferences.drawing.arrowPosition = EasyTipView.ArrowPosition.top
```

Further down in readme, it lists the legal arrow positions as `.top`, `.bottom`,`.left`,`.right`, and `.any`.

If you want your tool tip to appear below the view, you should try using`EasyTipView.ArrowPosition.top`.

Comment: Yes, that is EasyToolTip. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does that solve your problem then?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't It only changes where the arrow appears on the view

Comment: It should solve your problem....that's the purpose of changing the arrow position. It could be that your button is in a position that doesn't allow positioning the tooltip below in which case it's forced to put it on top. But in theory, @Stonereaper18's solution should work.

Comment: @Eric33187, Stonereaper18 is the one asking the question. I'm the one who suggested the answer. To Stonereaper, can you edit your question and add a screen-shot of the tool-tip when it is in the wrong location?

Comment: Oops sorry about that Duncan

Comment: @Eric33187, no worries. Full disclosure: I spent about 2 minutes scanning the readme for that library. I have no idea if the `arrowPosition` property will change the placement of the tooltip or not. It might **only** move the arrow.

Comment: I've used it before and it worked for me. But it was a while back

Comment: Yes, It worked there was a fault on my side. Thank You